# Import Android Packages from Desktop in Eclipse WorkSpace

Tags: android, eclipse, import, package

My friend made an Android App and send it to me.
Now I want to edit it in Eclipse but I don't know how to to do
that.
Anyone's know this?

Comment: no source code? only apk file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this way

Open your **Project Explorer** --> **right click on that** --> **imports** --> **General** --> **Existing Projects into workspace** --> **Browse** --> **Desktop** --> **Select Your Project** --> **OK**